# What does the linux "file" command consider "suspicious"?

Tags: linux

I was playing with the `file` command (the command-line utility used to identify file types) and I noticed one of the types it could match was "Suspicious"

What does that actually mean, what kind of files match it? Is there some program called "suspicious" that produces data `file` can identify? Does it match executable data that's in a file with a non-executable extension?

Comment: "*I noticed one of the types it could match was "Suspicious"*" Where and what exactly did you notice?

Comment: Looking at the results of `-file --list` on a few arbitrary files, one of the low-strength matches was "Suspicious".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic numbers definitions used by the `file` command are stored in [these files](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir).

The only occurrence of the description `Suspicious` points to a [certain byte in Flash files](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/flash#L24). It's actually the only occurrence of the string in the whole project.